# GeoTools: Creating a point and adding it to featureCollection

Tags: collections, gis, point, geotools

I am implementing an interpolation of trajectory points. So, basically, I need to create several points along the azimuth from a starting point to a destination point. The problem is, I can't add a created point to a collection:

```
SimpleFeatureType featureType = featureSource.getSchema(); 

GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory(null); 
SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(featureType); 

SimpleFeatureCollection collection = featureSource.getFeatures(); 

/* Irrelevant code here 
----------------------- 
*/ 

Point2D newPt = setPointByAzimuth(startingPointCoords, azimuth, distance_to_next_point); 

Point pointToCollection = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(newPt.getX(), newPt.getY())); 

featureBuilder.add(pointToCollection); //not quite sure what this does 

SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(null);       

collection.add(feature);
```

However, when I run this, the collection size does not change and nothing gets added to this collection. 
I am not sure what's the problem here.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

[Not every implementation of `SimpleFeatureCollection` is mutable](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/data/simple/SimpleFeatureCollection.html).

Try another way:

- create [`new DefaultFeatureCollection`](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/data/memory/MemoryFeatureCollection.html) and add your points to it;
- then add it to `MapContent` with [`addLayer`](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/map/MapContent.html#addLayer%28org.geotools.map.Layer%29).

Comment: The original problem is _"nothing gets added to this collection"_. That's correct. What I'm telling is to add *another* collection to the `MapContent`.

Comment: Sorry, there were a problem with SimpleFeatureType object which has been applied to the MemoryFeatureCollection as formal parameter at constructor, thus, nothing was shown. Sorry once again, Your solution helps me.